# Running wp-cli from bash script results in path error

Tags: bash, wp-cli

I have successfully installed wp-cli on my remote server and created the "wp" alias. I use Putty to connect via SSH, and everything works just fine. First, I used a .user_bashrc file to set the alias with:

```
alias wp='/www/htdocs/w019d58a/wp-cli.phar'
```

The path is set in .user_bashrc using:

```
export PATH=/www/htdocs/w019d58a/:$PATH
```

However, when I tried to run wp-cli from a bash script, I got a "wp command not found" error. I contacted the support, and they recommended a symlink. So, I created a symlink using:

```
ln -s /www/htdocs/w019d58a/wp-cli.phar wp
```

Everything works but the installation process. I can, for example, install a plugin using:

```
#!/bin/bash
wp plugin install akismet
```

Unfortunately, I can't download WordPress via the bash script using:

```
wp core download --locale=de_DE_formal
```

I always get the error:

```
Error: Too many positional arguments:
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
Pass --path=path/to/wordpress or run wp core download.
```

I tried to add the path using:

```
wp core download --locale=de_DE_formal --path="/www/htdocs/w019d58a"
```

No luck. I stil get the same error.

I can download and install WordPress directly from the console and do further operations using a script. But I can't download and install it from the script due to the path error.

Any ideas how to fix that?

I've just found out, that the download is working fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
wp core download --locale=de_DE_formal
```

It's the config create part that causes trouble:

```
wp config create --dbname=d123456 --dbuser=d123456 --dbpass=123456 --dbhost=localhost --dbprefix=wplcli_
```

Comment: Make sure the `--path=` is correct. Use absolute path, no `~`. Have to add `--path=` to all `wp` calls in the script, or first `cd` to the WP install directory.

Comment: I have the same issue but can't find out any solution.